# How to determine which Plans and Suites an individual Test Case belongs to in TestPlans for AzureDevOps

Tags: testing, azure-devops

Is there some way of discovering which Test Plans and/or Test Suites an individual Test Case has been used in?

In an ideal world, I'd also like to see all the previous outcomes for a particular Test Case.  For example, did it fail for a previous release?
.
.
.
I need to be able to start with the Test Case outside of the TestPlans screen.  I only have a Test Case number and don't know any of the Test Plans or Suites it's been put into.  We have a large number of Test Plans and I can't look in each one individually. 
[image]

Further update:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to determine which Plans and Suites an individual Test Case belongs to in TestPlans for AzureDevOps

You could select a test case, then click show/hide details pane. The Associated test suites pane shows you any test suite for any test plan that contains this test case. This includes all projects:

[image]

Then, we can view the test suites details in the test plan:

[image]

Check the [FAQs for manual testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops#q-how-can-i-find-out-if-a-test-case-was-added-to-other-test-suites) for some details.

Update:

[image]

Update2:

[image]

Help this helps.

Comment: I'm really new to this, so I don't know how you get to the screen where you have selected the Test Case.  A basic query doesn't seem to have this information on it.  I'd appreciate a little more guidance.

Comment: @SuW, Update the answer with a image. You could not get that info from basic query.

Comment: Sorry about this, but after I click 'Test Plans' (1), I don't see 'Test Cases' in the list.  I've added the image to the original post.

Comment: @SuW, You need add the test case into the test plan, check the update answer. You could check the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/?view=azure-devops for some more details.

Comment: Hi again, (and once again, sorry), but I already have Test Cases in Test Suites under the Test Plan.  But I'm not seeing 'Test Cases' on the left hand side of the screen.  I've attached another screen shot where you can see that I have Test Cases connected to the Product Backlog items to which they refer (one suite per backlog item).

Comment: @SuW, Oh, it's my fault. I installed the TestCaseExplorer plugin very early, and I forgot to remind you that you need to install it. You could get it from: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TestCaseExplorer. Install that extension, then you can view the test case tab, sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you, Leo.  That looks really useful and is the final piece of the puzzle. Your help has been very much appreciated.